# How can I generate a Bitmap from a winform control?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, bitmap

How can I generate a bitmap of a control on a winform using C#?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might try [Control.DrawToBitmap()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help: http://www.syncfusion.com/FAQ/windowsforms/faq_c3c.aspx#q870q

Answer (score 0):

Use Control.DrawToBitmap [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx)